# Mixing Flask and webapp2 on GAE

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine

Is it possible to place `webapp2` handler right inside `flask` application (on GAE)?

Specifically, I'd like to serve a blob with `send_blob(blob_key)` method of `google.appengine.ext.webapp.blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler`. Currently, I add it as a separate handler in `app.yaml`. Obviously, this has its drawback that the handler exists 'outside' of `Flask` framework so it cannot be 'cleanly' referenced from within `Flask` (e.g., with `url_for()` reverse lookup).